# seed_nonce_revelation

Tags: node

i wanted to understand the meaning of this transaction

{
                        "kind": "seed_nonce_revelation",
                        "level": 3872,
                        "nonce": "8202758af02e67400ffa9fa00b673876fd1797e18d17a73fe2c207f8623a3258",
                        "metadata": {
                            "balance_updates": [
                                {
                                    "kind": "freezer",
                                    "category": "rewards",
                                    "delegate": "tz3WMqdzXqRWXwyvj5Hp2H7QEepaUuS7vd9K",
                                    "level": 0,
                                    "change": "125000"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }

The balance_updates sections shows a change of 125000 as reward.

1.Is the reward immediately provided or it is freezed till it reaches the reward block or in another way if i want to find the balance of the delegate at block/level 3872 (assuming it was 0) will it be 125000 now with this reward ?

2. what is level :0 in the balance update section

Answer (score 1):

1. The reward is not immediately available, it is only available after 5 cycles (see [the documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/proof_of_stake.html)).
2. That should actually be the cycle of the block. It was probably a typo, corrected in the later protocol versions.

Comment: This particular block is the end block of Cycle 5 and that where i am asking is the fees , rewards of cycle 0 are given in this block

Comment: Indeed, the rewards obtained during cycle 0 should be available after the last block of cycle 5 has been applied.